# How to check the checkboxes in the table by using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: TABLE]

interviewer asked me that how would u click checkbox using a name from above table.
I need to check the 'THOMAS HARDY' checkbox. I didnt't know where the check box was but the only thing I knew was the name 'THOMAS HARDY' . how can I click checkbox with 'THOMAS HARDY'  using selenium web driver?

Comment: Assuming a clean and simple table with no inner divs spans etc, use xpath to get the td cell containing the 'Thomas Hardy' text. Go up to the parent tr. Then setup a \td\input[@type='checkbox']. This should get you the checkbox wherever it is placed in the row containing the text.

Comment: "interviewer asked me" if you need to ask us, the job is probably not for you...

Comment: DON'T SCREAM AT US

Comment: Read the documentation, it is available online and explains everything you need to know. Asking questions will not help you to understand basics of selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path_to_the_table/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'Thomas Hardy')]]/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

To explain what this does, first is obviously the path to the table itself, then the XPath points to the tr that contains a child td that contains the text 'Thomas Hardy', from this row it points to the first td in that row and then to the input in there.

From there it's just a case of telling selenium to click.

here's the important part for clarity:

```
tr[td//text()[contains(.,'Thomas Hardy')]]
```

You may obviously need to tweak this depending on the exact structure of the table and surrounding elements, but checking the row based on the contents of it's cells is all the same. Good luck with the interview!